# What are shopify's API shipping_line options?

Tags: shopify

I'm working on middleware between Shopify and a fulfillment company and I was able to obtain the UPS shipping methods given in Shopify's API but I need the rest of them to build a conversion table to the fulfillment companies shipping codes.

Here are the UPS codes:

- `UPS Ground`
- `UPS Second Day Air`
- `UPS Three-Day Select`
- `UPS Saver`
- `UPS Worldwide Expedited`
- `UPS Standard`
- `UPS Next Day Air Saver`
- `UPS Next Day Air`
- `UPS Next Day Air Early A.M.`
- `UPS Express`
- `UPS Worldwide Express Plus`
- `UPS Expedited`
- `UPS Second Day Air A.M.`
- `UPS Express Early A.M.`
- `UPS Ground 2`
- `UPS Standard 2`
- `UPS Second Day Air 2`
- `UPS Next Day Air 2`

Lines generated from UPS will look something like this:

`“shipping_lines”=>[{"title"=>"UPS Second Day Air", “code”=>"02", “price”=>25.63, “source”=>"ups"}]`

Answer (score 1):

Here are the possible titles for FedEx and USPS:

```
FedEx Ground
FedEx 2 Day
FedEx International First
FedEx International Economy
FedEx Standard Overnight
FedEx International Priority
FedEx Express Saver
FedEx Priority Overnight
FedEx First Overnight
FedEx Priority Overnight Saturday Delivery
FedEx 2 Day Saturday Delivery
FedEx First Overnight Saturday Delivery
FedEx International Priority Saturday Delivery
FedEx International Economy Freight
FedEx Ground Home Delivery
FedEx Europe First International Priority
FedEx International Priority 2

USPS Priority Mail
USPS First Class Mail International Package
USPS First-Class Mail
USPS Priority Mail International
USPS Parcel Post
USPS First-Class Mail Flat
USPS First-Class Mail Parcel
USPS Express Mail
USPS Express Mail International (EMS)
USPS Global Express Guaranteed
USPS First-Class Mail International Package
USPS Express Mail International
USPS Global Express Guaranteed (GXG)
USPS Express Mail 2
USPS Priority Mail 2
USPS First-Class Mail International Package**
USPS First-Class Mail Postcards
USPS First-Class Mail Large Envelope
USPS First-Class Mail Package
USPS First-Class Mail Letter
USPS Global Express Guaranteed (GXG)**
USPS Priority Mail International 2
USPS First-Class Mail International Parcel
```

Comment: David: where else is this list available?